# How to map a sub-directory on GAE to a different server on using python webapp2

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, webapp2

For SEO purposes I am trying to get a forum which is hosted on another server (google compute engine) to map to a sub-directory of my domain(on GAE) rather than just having a subdomain point at it. Like this:  example.com/forum rather than forum.example.com

I am using webapp2 on Google App Engine to host the main domain. Most everything I find about this is referencing Apache and .htaccess files not GAE webapp2. Is this possible with webapp2 or possibly the app.yaml?

Comment: Maybe in [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml)?

Comment: So you want `example.com` on GAE and `example.com/forum` on GCE?

Comment: Dan Cornilescu: I would like example.com/forum on GAE to point to the forum on GCE. the forum on GCE is just an IP address.  So you could browse and use the forum from my main domain without being redirected to a different domain.

Comment: snakecharmerb, thanks for the idea. I have been reading over the dispatch.yaml docs and it I am having a hard time figuring out if it would force a full redirect or allow a user to browse example.com/forum without leaving the root domain... Guess I will just have to try it out

Comment: I agree with @snakecharmerb solution. Let us know if it works.